# Visual SourceSafe - Get Latest version using batch file commands

Tags: batch-file, cmd, environment-variables, visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-2005

I'm attempting to write a batch file that will get the latest version automatically of ***only certain folders*** from SourceSafe.

***FILE LOCATIONS:***

SourceSafe is installed on my C drive:

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual SourceSafe*

The users.txt and data folder which contains um.dat are located in a Share on the Network:

*//Server* (I have mapped this folder to drive **X:** for convenience)

***.BAT FILE:***

```
@echo off

REM SET ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE TO LOCATION OF SS.EXE
PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual SourceSafe

REM SET DIR TO THE DATA DIRECTORY I.E. LOCATION OF SRCSAFE.INI
SET SSDIR = X:

REM LOGIN DETAILS
SET SSUSER = Administrator
SET SSPWD = Password

REM SET THE CURRENT PROJECT
ss CP $/Development/Websites/MySite

REM GET LATEST FROM THESE FOLDERS (RECURSIVE)
ss Get $/App_Code -I -Y -R -W
ss Get $/App_Data -I -Y -R -W
ss Get $/Bin -I -Y -R -W
ss Get $/Images -I -Y -R -W
ss Get $/scripts -I -Y -R -W
ss Get $/styles -I -Y -R -W

pause
```

***PROBLEM:***

When I run the file I get the following error:

**Invalid DOS path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual SourceSafe\data\um.dat**

It seems to be looking for these files in my C drive when it should be looking in the X drive. I've tried moving the problem files (um.dat and users.txt) from the X drive into that location on the C drive. The batch file will then run but I don't get the latest version.

If someone could help me figure this out I'd be very grateful!

Comment: did you get final solution using ***script bat*** ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your problem is that you are putting spaces around the `=` when you're doing a `set`.  You are creating an environment variable `SSDIR =`, which isn't the same as `SSDIR=`.

You can see this by doing the following in a CMD window:

```
C:\> set HELLO = this
C:\> set HELLO=that
C:\> set HELLO
HELLO=that
HELLO = this
```

Both exist, as the name of the environment variable is everything *up to* the equals, including the whitespace *before* the equals.

Sourcesafe will be looking for an environment variable called `SSDIR`, and that's not what you're setting.

Try changing the appropriate lines as follows:

```
REM SET DIR TO THE DATA DIRECTORY I.E. LOCATION OF SRCSAFE.INI
SET SSDIR=X:

REM LOGIN DETAILS
SET SSUSER=Administrator
SET SSPWD=Password
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
ss Get $/Development/Websites/MySite/App_Code -I -Y -R -W
```

instead of

```
ss Get $/App_Code -I -Y -R -W
```